# How to access labels from loop and change their text

Tags: c#

I have list where are 6 sentences which I want to put in 6 different labels.
All six labels are named Slot0Sentence, Slot1Sentence, Slot2Sentence...

This is how I loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < ls.Count; i++) 
{
    Slot0Sentence.Text = ls[i];
}
```

However I dont know how to access other labels.
If there would be normal string I would do Slot + i + Sentence but in this case this dont work.

Comment: put them in a *Label* array.... `var labels = new Label[]{Slot0Sentence, Slot1Sentence, Slot2Sentence, ...};`

Comment: Thanks! Im just starting coding in C# so didnt knew about array.

Comment: Instead of `array`, use a `List<Label>` unless you can loop through the `Labels` through the `Controls` collection of the `Parent`..

Comment: @Edgar did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with an array of labels you can control their properties. you don't need design here, you can do that with code.

```
Label[] l = new Label[6];
int x = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < l.Length; i++)
{
    l[i] = new Label();
    l[i].Name = "Hello " + i.ToString();
    l[i].Text = "Hello " + i.ToString();
    l[i].Location = new Point(x, 10);
    x += 100;
}
```

you can change the names and text to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use `Children` property of parent container (Grid, StackPanel,..). This gives you a collection which supports indexes. Additionally, in case you have different controls, use if statement

```
if(element in Label)
{
 element.Text = ...
}
```